# How to iterate over ApplicationRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have this:

```
a1.superclass
=> ApplicationRecord(abstract)
```

I want to iterate over all the records. This

```
a1.first
```

does work. However, how can I iterate? I've tried `each` and `[]` -- they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a1.all.each do |rec|
   puts rec.id
   ...
end
```

Comment: This is a total guess on my part. But your question is pretty thin on specifics so...

Comment: what do you mean by "on specifics **so** "?

Comment: so... my answer might not work for your particular situation. What is a1?